# Error: src/app/app.component.html:120:65 - error TS2339: Property 'employee' does not exist on type 'NgForm'. 120

Tags: angular

I am trying to use function, using Typescript 3.2.2 and I am getting errors. Can some one help please? This is the first solution I am trying to use a function `onUpdateEmployee` which I declared in `appcomponent.ts` and want to call in `app.component.html` from Angular, but this error appeared:

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:120:65 - error TS2339: Property
> 'employee' does not exist on type 'NgForm'.

TS

```
public onUpdateEmployee(employee: Employee): void{ 
  this.employeeService.updateEmployee(employee)
    .subscribe( (response: Employee) => { 
      console.log(response);
      this.getEmployees();  
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => { alert(error.message); } 
    ); 
}
```

Template:

```
<button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Close
</button> 
<button (click)="onUpdateEmployee(editForm.value)" 
  data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
  Save changes
</button>
```

Comment: code appcomponent.ts                                                                                                            public onUpdateEmployee(employee: Employee): void{
    this.employeeService.updateEmployee(employee).subscribe(
        (response: Employee) => {
           console.log(response);
               this.getEmployees();
      
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
        
      }
    );

  }

Comment: code appcomonent.html                                                                                                                                  <button  type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                   <button (click) = "onUpdateEmployee(editForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>

Comment: You need to include more code... Based on the error message I don't think the error is coming from the snippets you included